# What is the alignment of a packed structure in C?

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment, packing

Take the following struct:

```
struct s {
  char c; // 1 byte
  long l; // 8 bytes
};
```

C would add 7 bytes of padding between `c` and `l`, making the size of the struct 16 and the alignment of the struct 8. If I told the compiler to pack the struct, how is the alignment evaluated? Does it just give up and make the alignment 1 byte?

**EDIT:**

This question is not a duplicate of [Struct Padding and Packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing). I am asking how the **alignment of a packed struct** is evaluated. Not how padding is done or how the alignment of a regular struct is evaluated. If the above struct is **padded**, it has a size of 16 and an alignment of **8**--the alignment of its largest member (the `long`). If it is **packed**, it has a size of 9 bytes and an alignment of **?** bytes.

Comment: Wouldn't a quick test using sizeof() answer this?

Comment: @KenWhite No, it would not. Not a very complicated question. I am trying to understand the alignment of the packed struct, not the size.

Comment: @KenWhite Maybe I'm wrong. As far as I've been told, `sizeof` would just return `9`, and total size of a struct has nothing to do with its alignment. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If sizeof() returns a value that isn't a power of 2, there isn't any alignment, is there? Is 9 a power of 2? What would an alignment boundary be for 9?

Comment: Okay yes that applies for this struct. But let's say we have a struct with an `int` and a `long`, and it's packed. It's size is now 12 bytes rather than the usual 16 with packing. Would this be aligned on a 2 or 4 byte boundary, vice versa?

Comment: Is 12 a power of 2?

Comment: No it isn't. Sorry for my temper, I'm clearly not understanding alignment properly in the first place. Was getting frustrating not being able to find what seemed like a simple answer when I'm missing some key knowledge. Are you trying to say that if the size isn't a power of 2 it will just be placed at any address (alignment of 1)?